# Javascript Check whatever link is download link or webpage link

Tags: javascript, electron

It there anyway to check link whatever is a download link like http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip

or normal web like open https://www.google.com

Currently I am using Electron and want to check if link is download link it will download and not open new browser but if not it will open in browser window

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, mostly the download links are URI that have a file extension at the end like .pdf, .jpg, .png, .zip, .etc . so need to write a logic for this. Simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an HTTP request and check the `Content-Type` and (if it is there) `Content-Disposition` headers.

If `Content-Disposition` says it is an attachment, then it is a download. If it says it is inline, then it is intended to be displayed in the browser window.

If `Content-Disposition` isn't specified, then you'll need to make the decision based on the MIME type. e.g. `text/html` should probably be shown in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

May be check the end of the link... if it ends with .zip .jpg .pdf .... it is a file.
Or .html ... it is a page.